# org-mode clock tables and charts

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to generate for `org-mode` (logging work), a two-dimensional table where rows are tasks and columns are successive days of a week/month or successive weeks, cells are the time; or a corresponding chart?

I'm only aware of the hacky `rangereport` from http://sachachua.com/blog/2007/12/clocking-time-with-emacs-org/

Comment: What I haven't realized at the time of asking is that `clocktable` has a `:step` parameter. So one approach would be to scan the clocktable `:tstart ... :step ... :tend ...` and collect the numbers.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't completely understand what kind of a table you require, but you could press Shift+R (`org-agenda-clockreport-mode`) on your agenda buffer to see a table with tasks in rows sorted according to projects and how much time was spent on it. You could change the scope of the table by changing the time period of the agenda and rebuilding the agenda.

[image]

You could also use `C-c C-x C-d` or `org-agenda-columns` in the org file itself to get a task-wise overview.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like a 2D table, where columns are successive days or weeks, as in `clocktable :step`. I didn't know about the `:step` option of `clocktable` at the time of asking.